# right way to write to file from different threads (using Qt c++ )

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, locking

i have thread pool that create threads each thread worker calculate some work and when it done
it writes the result to file , there is only 1 result file , that each worker thread needs to write to .
now my question is how i guarantee that there wouldn't be any locks or missing write data to the file where allot of threads trying to write to single file ? what is the right strategy for such scenario?
mybe keep all result in memory ? or chanks of results

im using already the QThreadPool framework , and i need to find solution with it.
also i wander , does writing to single file from worker threads , i will have to use
singleton file manager or static class , is it good idea? for multithreaded app ?

Comment: Maybe a semaphore can help http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/threads-semaphores.html

Comment: According to your description, [QtConcurrent::mappedReduced](http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/qtconcurrentmap.html#mappedReduced) may be usefull

Comment: what solution to you offer ? keep result in memory ?

Comment: You create your own `Runnable` deriving from `QRunnable`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you have many concurrent threads competing for one shared resource. That begs a synchronization primitive of some sort, for example a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex).

Here's (non-Qt specific) code showcasing 10 threads simultaneously writing to a single file. On a side note, C++11 introduced a lot of goodies like `std::mutex` (and `std::thread` too, so that can help eliminate some Qt-specific threading code).

```
#include <fstream>   
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>    
#include <vector>

std::mutex m;
std::ofstream file;

int main() {
  file.open("file.txt");

  std::vector<std::thread> workers;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {       
    workers.push_back(std::thread([=i] {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        file << "thread " << i << ": " << j << endl;
      }
    }));
  }
  for (auto& worker : workers) {
    worker.join();
  }

  file.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, if you have a lot of places in your code accessing the shared resource, it's better to encapsulate it, along with the mutex, in some "accessor" class that would manage all state-modifying calls to the resource.

P.S. If you're not on C++11 compiler, you can use `boost::mutex` or Qt-specific mutex wrapper. The key thing is that you need *some* synchronization primitive associated with the shared resource.

Answer (score 2):

As I assume, you crate your own `Runnable`, deriving from `QRunnable`

You can pass some context information when constructing your `Runnable` class. You need to pass device to write in and `mutex` to lock device, for example.

```
class Runnable: public QRunnable
{
public:
    Runnable(QIOdevice* device, QMutex* mutex):_d(device), _m(mutex){}
    void run()
    {
        saveInFile();
    }

private:
    void saveInFile()
    {
        QMutexLocker lock(_m);
        //now only one thread can write to file in the same moment of time
        device->write(...);
    }

    QIOdevice* _d;
    QMutex* _m;
};
```

Comment: Don't forget to unlock the mutex once the write has been completed.

Comment: @Pedro, `QMutexLocker` works like `std::lock_guard`. It unlocks mutex after goes out of scope. it implements RAII-style locking mechanism